# how to parse JSON response and store it on contact

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, apex-webservice

```
  {
  "data":[
    {
      "status":"found",
      "contact":{
        "salesforceId":"{id}"
        "firstName": "First (first)",
        "lastName": "LastName",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "phone": "94120129120",
      }
    }
```

the above JSON response is stored on a field in sf

```
jsonMap = (Map<String, Object>)responseItem.get('contact');
contact.reponse__c = JSON.serialize(jsonMap);
```

Parsing the firstname to contact like this

```
contact.FirstName = String.valueOf(jsonMap.get('firstName'));
```

Now how can I parse the value in "()" of firstname to store it on a field on contact.

Comment: You could you [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) for generating a JSON parser class. Once you could get the necessary values, you can perform standard String operations to further process the retrieved data before writing on a Contact.

Comment: you need to use a regex on the `contact.firstname` to extract the contents of the string delimited by () or .. you could use the `substringBetween` method of string class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `contact.FirstName` has the value 'First (first)' , you can extract the contents of the parenthesized expression using

```
String parentheticalName = String.isNotBlank(contact.FirstName)
    ? contact.FirstName.substringBetween('(',')')
    : null;
```

If you have more complex pattern matching to do, use the [Apex Pattern and Matcher classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm?search_text=regex) that do regex evaluation.